# computeTriangles returning number from 0 to 4

Tags: java, libgdx

I have got these verticles:

```
float[] verticles={100+i*200, 100, 100+i*200, 200, 140+i*200, 210, 160+i*200, 220, 180+i*200,100};
```

And I'm trying to cut this polygon  to triangles to fill it with color or texture:

```
EarClippingTriangulator triangulator = new EarClippingTriangulator();

ShortArray triV=triangulator.computeTriangles(verticles);
```

And after displaying results:

```
for(int i=0; i<triV.size; i+=1){
     System.out.println(triV.toArray()[i]);
}
```

I've got this:

4
0
1
4
1
2
2
3
4

I wanted verticles of these triangles, but I've got some numbers from 0 to 4.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: yes, is it OK ? if not, could you explain ?

Comment: Is should have returned verticles of triangles made of that polygon (i guess), but it returned only numbers from 0 to 4.

Comment: We need information about EarClippingTriangulator, ShortArray , etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [document](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/EarClippingTriangulator.java) says `computeTriangles` returns "triples of triangle indices in clockwise order".

So "4" in "4 0 1 4 1 2 2 3 4" means the 4th point that is (180+i*200, 100).

There are three triangles 4-0-1, 4-1-2, 2-3-4.

Comment: It make it sense. Thanks